# Flutter how to add values and show

Tags: flutter

I have json data like this

```
{
            "OrderID": 208,
            "CustomerID": 2,
            "TransactionNo": 80,
            "OrderNo": 1,
 
            "OrderDetails": [
                {
                
                    "ItemName": "Water",
                    "Price": 2.0,

                },
                {
  
                    "ItemName": "Water",
                    "Price": 2.0,
  
                }
            ],
}
```

I am showing this data in my stateful widget. But issue is now i need to calculate the price and show in a widget. I need to sumup the Orderdetails['price'] and show in a Text widget i am stuck at this point

```
  class OrderDetails extends StatefulWidget {
  Map<String, dynamic> text;

  // receive data from the FirstScreen as a parameter
  OrderDetails({Key key, @required this.text}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _OrderDetailsState createState() => _OrderDetailsState();
}

class _OrderDetailsState extends State<OrderDetails> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(widget.text);

    double stackWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double stackHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            color: Colors.white,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  if (widget.text['CustomerOrders'] != null)
                    Text(
                      (widget.text['CustomerOrders'] as Map)['Name']
                              .toString() ??
                          "N/A",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'SFPROBOLD',
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 17),
                    ),

          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'Total (incl, Tax)',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 15,
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  'I need to show the total value here',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'SFPROBOLD',
                      fontSize: 15,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),


        ],
      ),
    ))]));
  }
}
```

You can see in code i am showing the values like widget.text but don't know how can i sump the values ok OrderDetails and show in a text widget

Comment: can you get a the prices as a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var order = jsonDecode(your_json);
var details = order['OrderDetails'];
var total = 0.0;
details.forEach((i) {
  total+=i['Price'];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the sum of a list use this one, I  assume you can get the price as a list.

```
int sum = price.fold(0, (previous, current) => previous + current);
```

I would advise you to use classes to decode the json rather than iterate over the map. To quickly generate a decoder class paste your json on https://quicktype.io/, then pass it as to a FutureBuilder

Comment: how it wokrs in my code ? if i just need to add priced i think i need to add loop or something

Comment: Do you have a way of measuring the length of the list

Comment: nup i think need to use foreach loop add all amount in one array and calculate it ?